# Command 'gopls.go_get_package' failed

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

V.S Code shows following error in Problems

```
could not import context (no required module provides package "context")
```

Although the build generates without an issue.
However whenever I click, Quick Fix and then go get context
VS Code gives following error :

```
Command 'gopls.go_get_package' failed: Error: err: exit status 1: stderr: template: main:1:9: executing "main" at <.Module.Path>: nil pointer evaluating *modinfo.ModulePublic.Path .
```

The show trace option shows

```
[Error - 9:19:23 AM] 2022/04/04 09:19:23 command error: err: exit status 1: stderr: template: main:1:9: executing "main" at <.Module.Path>: nil pointer evaluating *modinfo.ModulePublic.Path
```

[Error - 9:19:23 AM] Request workspace/executeCommand failed.
Message: err: exit status 1: stderr: template: main:1:9: executing "main" at <.Module.Path>: nil pointer evaluating *modinfo.ModulePublic.Path

Code: 0

Comment: `context` package should be in the standard package, so the error usually indicates problem in workspace initialization.  Check the notification area to see if there is any error from the extension. Often I saw issues related to the limitation of the go language server described here https://github.com/golang/vscode-go#setting-up-your-workspace